# Space opera about two humanoid races at war.

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read the subject book in 1981 and it wasn't new then. The book probably would be described today as a space opera.

From what I can remember there is an intersolar system war between two solar system races NOTE humanoid, not human. One planet is eventually destroyed  (the asteroid belt) and the other is laid waste...

There is a colony on the dark side of the moon that is destroyed in a massive meteor storm with the survivors walking to rescue on the moons surface gradually dying off until only # one makes it through sheer bloody minded determination to the rescue site where a small number of survivors revamp to earth
Now the story swaps back and forwards with many reverses and twists but in the end archaeologists find the one walkers equipment buried for over 2000 yrs...aka  our forefathers..

And that's what I can remember, the story is intense and the revelations during the book are stunning I seem to remember.

Comment: Based on the OP's agreeing that the answer is correct in a comment, voting to close as duplicate.  There are at least 2 other questions with this answer but it wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 10):

[That would be "Inherit the Stars" from James P. Hogan , 1977.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giants_(series))

Just one planet, though.  There's a war on the planet.  The two parties in the war have colonies on the moon, and there are battles on the moon.

There are two friends (Koriel, who survives and whose stuff is found on the earth and his buddy whose name I have forgotten.)

They are part of group of survivors who landed on the moon, and now have to march to another base where they hope to find air and water.

The guy whose name I can't remember dies on the march.  Koriel leaves his dead friend in a protected spot.

The dead guy is eventually found on the earth's moon, and causes a sensation.

He causes even more confusion when his diary is translated.  He consistently mentions being on the moon of his home planet, and tells the story up to just before he died.

Eventually, the main character of the story figures out that the home planet of the dead guy was destroyed (which creates the asteroid belt.) The moon of the planet falls inwards toward the sun, and is eventually captured by the earth to become our moon.

Koriel survived all of that, and landed on the earth.

The book ends with a group of archeologists finding an armband/electronic watch kind of thing while digging up caveman stuff.  They throw it away under the assumption that it is some modern junk.

The armband has the owner's name on it: Koriel.

---

The people on the destroyed planet were not human, but close.  Aliens had abducted specimens of earlier hominds from the earth and set them on planet that ended up destroyed.  They weren't human, but close enough to breed with humans.

It is a very good book that connects a lot of real things together.  The connections are fictional, but fun.

Comment: 'Giants' series by James P. Hogan. The first book is called "Inherit the Stars" and is about the discovery of the antiquated corpse on Luna.

Comment: Boom Koriel that's it.Thank you very much.